# TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Textarea from "react-textarea-autosize";

class InputSet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }


  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    body: PropTypes.string
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.title.focus();
  }

  render() {
    const { onChange, title, body } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <TitleInput
          name="title"
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder="Title"
          innerRef={ref => (this.title = ref)}
          value={title}
        />
        <StyledTextArea
          minRows={3}
          maxRows={20}
          placeholder="Please enter a note..."
          name="body"
          onChange={onChange}
          value={body}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InputSet;
```

When I click on a component, that error suddenly occurs. And it says **TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined**

The error is occured at **componentDidMount**

Can you take the time to help me fix this error?

I can't understand why this error is coming up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, `title` is not a class property of your `InputSet` component.

I believe you meant to make use of the `React.createRef()` API to attach the `ref` to your React element.

```
this.title = React.createRef();
```

On your constructor,

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
  this.title = React.createRef();
}
```

And then,

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.title.current) {
    this.title.current.focus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.current` like this `this.title.current.focus();`

Hope this helps

Comment: for version >16.3